# Binding `Play.current.configuration` using dependency injection in Play 2.5?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, guice, securesocial

I'm using Guice dependency injection in my Play 2.5 application, along with SecureSocial. SecureSocial's `Registration` controller [calls](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/controllers/Registration.scala#L95) a (deprecated) `Play.current.configuration` [value](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/core/providers/UsernamePasswordProvider.scala#L127) eagerly, which so far as I can tell is incompatible with DI, and therefore I get a `java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application` error immediately at runtime. Is there a way I can ensure that `Play.current.configuration` is bound by Guice and thus available to the SecureSocial library? Or is my only option to re-write the Registration controller to call the configuration lazily?

Comment: `Play.current` cannot be bound to anything, because it's essentially a static field. Also, you're saying it binds eagerly, but you link to a lazy val? Where is this required from?

Comment: @rethab I added some links in my post. SecureSocial's registration controller has a `val form` (not lazy) which calls the configuration. See https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/controllers/Registration.scala#L95 and https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/core/providers/UsernamePasswordProvider.scala#L127

Comment: Well then.. let's face it, securesocial is practically unmaintained. I'd look for alternatives.

Comment: @rethab fair enough. Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, Play2-Auth worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

SecureSocial is on the way to support Play 2.5

There is a 3.0-M6 version (12 days ago), did you try it?

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/securesocial/YcrAay9eO2M

https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial

Comment: Yep! You can see that's the one I'm referring to in my links.